# What package does create-react-app docs use

Tags: documentation

I am wondering how I can create a docs site like [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) or [react typescript cheatsheets](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/). I am imaging they are using the same package or setup, I just want to know what they are using. Apologies if the answer is too obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I discovered they are using [docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/).